# insert title of articles in guillemets in ConTeXt bibliographies

Tags: bibliographies, context

What shall I do to have articles title within french guillemets in a structural way? I have tryied this so far, but without success, whatever style I choose (APA, APS, Chicago). Compiled under LMTX, for the records. Playing with the style setups did not help very much neither.

```
\setuppapersize[A4]
\mainlanguage[fr]
\language[fr]

\startbuffer [bib]
@article{IslamIran,
   author = "Sétareh Gaffari",
   title = "Islam et politique en Iran",
   journal = "CEMOTI",
   number = "39--40",
   year = "2005",
   pages = {125--136},
   doi = "https://doi.org/10.3406/cemot.2005.1769",
   url = "https://www.persee.fr/doc/cemot_0764-9878_2005_num_39_1_1769"
}

\stopbuffer

\usebtxdataset[bib.buffer]

\usebtxdefinitions [apa] 

%\setupbtx [apa:list:title:article]
%    [left={«},
%     right={»}]

%does not work neither
\setupbtx [apa:list:title:article]
    [left={\btxlabeltext{«}},
     right={\btxlabeltext{»}}]


\starttext

\nocite[IslamIran]

\placelistofpublications
\stoptext
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `\quotation` command.

```
\setupbtx
    [apa:list:title:article]
    [command=\quotation]
```

Full example (tested with MkIV and LMTX):

```
\setuppapersize[A4]
\mainlanguage[fr]
\language[fr]

\startbuffer [bib]
@article{IslamIran,
   author = "Sétareh Gaffari",
   title = "Islam et politique en Iran",
   journal = "CEMOTI",
   number = "39--40",
   year = "2005",
   pages = {125--136},
   doi = "https://doi.org/10.3406/cemot.2005.1769",
   url = "https://www.persee.fr/doc/cemot_0764-9878_2005_num_39_1_1769"
}

\stopbuffer

\usebtxdataset[bib.buffer]

\usebtxdefinitions [apa] 

\setupbtx
    [apa:list:title:article]
    [command=\quotation]

\starttext

\nocite[IslamIran]

\placelistofpublications
\stoptext
```

[image]