# Dot after author name in Chicago style - Context

Tags: bibliographies, context, chicago-style

How do I put a dot after the author (first) name in the bibliography?

```
\startbuffer [bib]
@article{fulano,
   author = "Fulano de Tal",
   title = "Um título chamativo",
   journal = "Jornal de Maio",
   number = "31--44",
   year = "2008",
   pages = "125--136",
   url = "https://www.google.com"
}

\stopbuffer

\usebtxdataset[bib.buffer]

\usebtxdefinitions [chicago] 


\starttext

\nocite[fulano]

\placelistofpublications
\stoptext
```

I'd like to appear as **de Tal, Fulano. 2008.** etc.

As an aside, I haven't been able to make the "vancouver" style work (I guess it's not implemented yet?)

Comment: It probably would be easier to do with `biblatex-chicago`.

Comment: @Bernard, judging from the answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/514930/insert-title-of-articles-in-guillemets-in-context-bibliographies], I surmised it was a piece of cake (at least for he ones in the know).

Comment: You have to know that it's generally easier to customise bibliography with `biblatex`, since it uses a latex-like syntax. Also, the `xparse` package enables to patch biblatex internal commands.

Comment: @Bernard, thanks for the input. I'll wait for an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a look in `publ-imp-chicago.mkvi`, and it seems that the author and year are set together in the `btx:chicago:authoryear` command. One could redefine that command, but I do not know if that is according to the chicago style or not. If it is, I suggest that you write to the author about it.

In any case, the following seem to work. *Disclaimer* I do not understand know if this has any unwanted side effects or if there is a better way to do this.

Finally, I have no clue about the vancouver style.

```
\startbuffer [bib]
@article{fulano,
   author = "Fulano de Tal",
   title = "Um título chamativo",
   journal = "Jornal de Maio",
   number = "31--44",
   year = "2008",
   pages = "125--136",
   url = "https://www.google.com"
}
\stopbuffer

\usebtxdataset[bib.buffer]

\usebtxdefinitions [chicago] 

\starttexdefinition mutable protected btx:chicago:authoryear
    % we make the authoryear active, pointing to the citation
    \texdefinition{btx:format:inject}
        {internal(\currentbtxinternal)}
        {
            \doifelsesetups{chicago:list:sameauthor} {
                \btxdoifelsesameasprevious {author} {
                    \fastsetup{chicago:list:sameauthor}
                } {
                    \texdefinition{btx:chicago:author-or-editor} {author}
                }
            } {
                \texdefinition{btx:chicago:author-or-editor} {author}
            }
            %This \btxperiod is my only addition
            \btxperiod
            \texdefinition{btx:chicago:suffixedyear}
        }
    % outside of interaction
    \btxperiod
    \doif {\btxfoundname{author}} {title} {
        \setmode{btx:chicago:title-placed}
    }
\stoptexdefinition



\starttext

\nocite[fulano]

\placelistofpublications
\stoptext
```

The result at least looks as I understand you want it:

[image: The bibliography with an extra dot after the author]