# Chicago style in ConTeXt: Firstname and Lastname for second and subsequent authors, and dot after the last author name

Tags: bibliographies, context

The title should sum up my questions:

1. Does ConTeXt have a "proper" Chicago style now?
2. If it does not, please tell me how I can make **the second and subsequent authors** in the following MWE be listed as Firstname Lastname instead of Lastname, Firstname?
3. I also need the dot after the final author's name. I use @mickep answer from [Dot after author name in Chicago style - Context](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/627398/dot-after-author-name-in-chicago-style-context), but if authors are many and "et al." is used, there will be a double dot like in the second reference in the MWE. How can we fix this?

Thank you for any help on this.

```
\startbuffer[bib]

@article{abu-ghaida2004,
   title = {The costs of missing the Millennium Development Goal on gender equity},
   volume = {32},
   doi = {10.1016/j.worlddev.2004.02.003},
   number = {7},
   journal = {World Development},
   author = {Dina Abu-Ghaida and Stephan Klasen},
   year = {2004},
   pages = {1075--1107},
}
@incollection{apostolopoulos2018,
   address = {UK},
   title = {Entrepreneurship and the Sustainable Development Goals},
   volume = {8},
   isbn = {978-1-78756-376-6 978-1-78756-375-9},
   booktitle = {Contemporary Issues in Entrepreneurship Research},
   publisher = {Emerald Publishing Limited},
   author = {Nikolaos Apostolopoulos and Haya Al-Dajani and Diane Holt and Paul Jones and Robert Newbery},
   editor = {Nikolaos Apostolopoulos and Haya Al-Dajani and Diane Holt and Paul Jones and Robert Newbery},
   year = {2018},
   doi = {10.1108/S2040-724620180000008005},
   pages = {1--7},
}
\stopbuffer

\usebtxdataset[default][bib.buffer]
\loadbtxdefinitionfile[chicago]
\usebtxdefinitions[chicago]
\setupbtx[dataset=default]
\definebtxrendering[default][chicago][specification=chicago,sorttype=authoryear,numbering=no]

% These lines came from mickep, see <https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/627398/dot-after-author-name-in-chicago-style-context>

\starttexdefinition mutable protected btx:chicago:authoryear
    % we make the authoryear active, pointing to the citation
    \texdefinition{btx:format:inject}
        {internal(\currentbtxinternal)}
        {
            \doifelsesetups{chicago:list:sameauthor} {
                \btxdoifelsesameasprevious {author} {
                    \fastsetup{chicago:list:sameauthor}
                } {
                    \texdefinition{btx:chicago:author-or-editor} {author}
                }
            } {
                \texdefinition{btx:chicago:author-or-editor} {author}
            }
            %This \btxperiod is my only addition
            \btxperiod
            \texdefinition{btx:chicago:suffixedyear}
        }
    % outside of interaction
    \btxperiod
    \doif {\btxfoundname{author}} {title} {
        \setmode{btx:chicago:title-placed}
    }
\stoptexdefinition

\starttext

\startbodymatter

Instead of {\bf Lastname, Firstname} for all authors \cite[abu-ghaida2004], the names of second and subsequent authors should be sorted as {\bf Firstname Lastname}, i.e., Abu-Ghaida, Dina and Stephan Klasen for the first reference. Similarly, it should be Apostolopoulos, Nikolaos, Haya Al-Dajani, Diane Holt et al. for the second one. The sorting should be almost similar to the list of editors in the second reference (except the first editor). How can we do this?

\blank
When et al. is used in the list of authors, there will be a double dot before the year of publication \cite[apostolopoulos2018]. How can we fix this?

\blank
Thank you.

\blank[2cm]
\placelistofpublications[criterium=all]

\stopbodymatter

\stoptext
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following seems to match the recommendations in CMOS 17:

```tex
\setuppagenumbering[state=stop]

% Load the base Chicago style
\setupinteraction[state=start]
\usebtxdefinitions[chicago]


% The sample data from the original question
\startbuffer[bib]
@article{abu-ghaida2004,
   title = {The costs of missing the Millennium Development Goal on gender equity},
   volume = {32},
   doi = {10.1016/j.worlddev.2004.02.003},
   number = {7},
   journal = {World Development},
   author = {Dina Abu-Ghaida and Stephan Klasen},
   year = {2004},
   pages = {1075--1107},
}
@incollection{apostolopoulos2018,
   address = {UK},
   title = {Entrepreneurship and the Sustainable Development Goals},
   volume = {8},
   isbn = {978-1-78756-376-6 978-1-78756-375-9},
   booktitle = {Contemporary Issues in Entrepreneurship Research},
   publisher = {Emerald Publishing Limited},
   author = {Nikolaos Apostolopoulos and Haya Al-Dajani and Diane Holt and Paul Jones and Robert Newbery},
   editor = {Nikolaos Apostolopoulos and Haya Al-Dajani and Diane Holt and Paul Jones and Robert Newbery},
   year = {2018},
   doi = {10.1108/S2040-724620180000008005},
   pages = {1--7},
}
\stopbuffer

\usebtxdataset[bib.buffer]


% Adjust some configuration settings
\setupbtx[chicago:list][
    authorconversion=invertedfirst, % §15.9
    etallimit=10, % §14.76
    etaldisplay=7, % §14.76
]


\setupbtx[chicago:cite][
    etallimit=3, % §15.29
    etaldisplay=1, % §15.29
    otherstext={\btxspace\btxlabeltext{others}}, % §15.29
]


\setupbtx[chicago:list:editor][
    authorconversion=normal, % §15.9
]


\setupbtx[chicago:doi][
    style=tt, % Personal preference
]


\setupbtx[chicago:list:volume][
    style=tf, % §14.171
]


\setupbtx[chicago:list:title:article][
    command=\quotation, % §14.169
]


\setupbtx[chicago:list:title:incollection][
    style=it, % §15.41
]


\setupbtxlabeltext[en][
    chicago:editedby={edited by},
    chicago:In={In},
    chicago:of={of},
]


% Patch the commands
\starttexdefinition mutable protected btx:chicago:editor-in
    % See §§15.41–15.42
    \btxdoif {booktitle} {
        \btxdoifelse {volume} {
            \btxlabeltext{chicago:Volume}
            \btxspace
            \btxflush{volume}
            \btxspace
            \btxlabeltext{chicago:of}
        } {
            \btxlabeltext{chicago:In}
        }

        \btxspace
        \texdefinition{btx:chicago:composed-title}{booktitle}

        \doifnot {\btxfoundname{author}} {editor} {
            \btxcomma
            \btxlabeltext{chicago:editedby}
            \btxspace
            \btxflush{editor}
        }
        \btxperiod
    }
\stoptexdefinition


\starttexdefinition mutable protected btx:chicago:editionset
    % See §14.113
    \btxdoif {edition} {
        \btxperiod
        \btxflush{edition}
        \btxspace
        \btxlabeltext{chicago:edition}
    }
\stoptexdefinition


\starttexdefinition mutable protected btx:chicago:doi
    % See §14.8
    \btxstartstyleandcolor[chicago:doi]
        \setbreakpoints[doi]
            \texdefinition {btx:format:goto} {
                url(https://doi.org/\btxflush{doi})
            } {
                \hyphenatedurl{https://doi.org/\btxflush{doi}}
            }
    \btxstopstyleandcolor
    \btxperiod
\stoptexdefinition


\starttexdefinition unexpanded expanded btx:chicago:suffixedyear
    % Remove the "double dot" (but not needed with the included demo data)
    \removeunwantedspaces \removepunctuation \btxperiod
    \normalunexpanded \expandafter \expandafter \expandafter {\lastnamedcs}
\stoptexdefinition


\starttexdefinition mutable protected btx:chicago:journal-volume-number-pages
    % See §15.47
    \btxspace
    \texdefinition{btx:chicago:journal}
    \btxdoifelse {volume} {
        \btxcomma
        \texdefinition{btx:chicago:volume}
        \btxdoif {number} {
            \btxleftparenthesis
            \btxflush{number}
            \btxrightparenthesis
        }
    } {
        \btxdoif {number} {
            \btxcomma
            \btxlabeltext{chicago:number}
            \btxflush{number}
        }
    }
    \btxdoif {pages} {
        \btxcolon
        \btxflush{pages}
    }
    \btxperiod
\stoptexdefinition


% Demonstration
\starttext
    First \cite[abu-ghaida2004], second \cite[apostolopoulos2018].

    \subject{References}
    \placelistofpublications
\stoptext
```

[image: sample output]

> 1. Does ConTeXt have a "proper" Chicago style now?

Kind of, but as you can see above it needs a little bit of work to be fully-correct.

> 2. If it does not, please tell me how I can make the second and subsequent authors in the following MWE be listed as Firstname Lastname instead of Lastname, Firstname?

```tex
\setupbtx[chicago:list][
    authorconversion=invertedfirst,
]
```

(undocumented, but seems to work)

> 3. I also need the dot after the final author's name. I use @mickep answer from Dot after author name in Chicago style - Context, but if authors are many and "et al." is used, there will be a double dot like in the second reference in the MWE. How can we fix this?

Replace `\btxperiod` with `\removeunwantedspaces\removepunctuation\btxperiod` essentially, but see the definition of `btx:chicago:suffixedyear` for the full command.

> Bibliography styles (CMOS any edition, APA 7th, etc), I think, are not ConTeXt forte by default.

APA should be perfect in ConTeXt. From [the manual](https://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/mkiv-publications.pdf#page=30):

> *A note on the APA style:* We get the strong impression that the APA
> bibliography style standard was made with the implicit assumption that
> manual intervention would be involved in the editing and production
> process; It has been an arduous task to create a system capable of
> fully conforming to these specifications.
>
> [...]
>
> We have made (and continue to make) a
> great effort to scrupulously respect the APA style in the so-named
> rendering.

The APS style is also pretty good, mainly because it is so simple. The Chicago style is fairly incomplete though, mostly because it is *incredibly* complex and confusing to follow.

Comment: I agree to some extent that CMOS is incredibly complex. The example given is enough for my use case and I accepted the answer.